# Update oracle com informações distintas

Tags: sql, oracle

Estou tentando fazer um update no oracle com informações completamente distintas e não sei como fazer. Eu quero que todos os outros campus estejam igual ao campus 1, onde esse id_campu é uma foreign key com outra tabela.
Exemplo:

`col1.id | col2.descricao |col3.id_campus| col4.flag
 1        desc1            1               a
 2        desc2            1               b 
 3        desc3            1               c
 4        desc2            1               d 
 5        desc3            1               e
 6        1desc            2               a
 7        1desc            2               b 
 8        1desc            2               c
 9        desc2            2               b 
 10       desc1            2               c
 11       1desc            3               b
 12       d1esc            3               d 
 13       d1esc            3               c
 14       desc2            3               e 
 15       des1c            5               a`

```
UPDATE table1 t1
   SET (descricao, flag) = 
       (SELECT t2.descricao, t2.flag
          FROM table1 t2
         WHERE t1.id_campus = 1
       )
 WHERE t1.id_campus in (select t3.id_campus from table1 t3 where t3.id_campus not in (1));
```

Só que aí, dá o erro: ORA-01427: a subconsulta de uma única linharetorna mais de uma linha.

Comment: Melhore o exemplo descrevendo as tabelas, confesso não tem entendido este "id_campus = 1" e "id_campus = 1" , em princípio um bloco plsql com um cursor deve resolver a questão.

Comment: Como o @Motta citou para a situação que mencionou será necessário um bloco plsql utilizando um select(cursor) em um FOR passando estes parâmetros distintos para o update. [LINK plsql para entender melhor](http://www.devmedia.com.br/pl-sql-functions-e-procedures/29882)

Comment: E o perguntador some ...

Answer (score 0):

Parece que no select abaixo, está retornando mais de um id_campus = 1... Crendo que nessa "table1" ele é foreign de uma tabela "campus", por exemplo.

> (SELECT t2.descricao, t2.flag
>             FROM table1 t2
>            WHERE t1.id_campus = 1
>          )

Com base em todos os campus precisam ter a descricao e flag igual ao campus 1, poderia fazer:

```
UPDATE table1
SET DESCRICAO = ( SELECT DESCRICAO FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID_CAMPUS = 1 )
    , FLAG = ( SELECT FLAG FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID_CAMPUS = 1 )
WHERE ID_CAMPUS <> 1
```

Mas lembre de se garantir que nessa table1 tem apenas um registro pro campus 1, senão pode ser um erro de base, ou talvez tenha uma data de vigência dessas características...